# when does static_cast compile to no CPU instructions

Tags: c++, static-cast

This question is motivated by the following (simplified) example.

```
Consider the following code:

void f(unsigned int x) { }

int main()
{
  int z = 3;
  
  if (z > 0)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
      f(i);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with all warnings enabled, the compiler issues a

```
warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’
```

This is clearly not a real problem, since the code explicitly checks that the upper limit in the for loop is positive.

One way to eliminate the warning is to explicitly [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) z:

```
int main()
{
  int z = 3;
  
  if (z > 0)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned int>(z); ++i)
      f(i);

  return 0;
}
```

At least in this simplified example, both codes compile to the same assembler, see it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G4Gc83bvE).
Indeed, I would not expect that a cast from an int to unsigned int to result in any instructions, since both types are [stored with the same number of bits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Which leads to the question: when does `static_cast` result in no compiled instructions? Is this always the case for a `static_cast` between integers having the same size in bits?

Comment: Those are internal implementation details; consult the documentation for your particular implementation. That said, on a typical two's complement machine, converting between signed and unsigned counterparts of the same integral type is indeed a no-op, since both use the same bit representation.

Comment: in this generallity its a rather open ended question. Note that `static_cast` can trigger custom conversions that can do anything you like and then it depens on how good the compiler can optimize it. Just a silly example https://godbolt.org/z/1rjE667br.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not even sure what this claim means. If I have `char* p = "hello"; static_cast<std::string>(p);` are you saying no code would execute at run time to construct the `std::string`? How exactly do you define the term "compile-time conversion"?

Comment: compiler doesn't care about your if statement, it only knows that ```z``` has sign bit used for sign, whereas sing bit of ```i``` doesn't exist and bit ```31``` th is just another bit.

Comment: Note that "stored in the same number of bits" isn't sufficient to avoid conversion instructions. Maybe `double` and `int` have the same number of bits on a platform, but clearly converting one to the other requires some work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't have the cast there, the compiler [adds a conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Arithmetic_comparison_operators) for you anyway, so it makes sense that they both compile to identical machine code. But when it is implicit, it's likely that you weren't expecting or even aware of that (just search on StackOverflow for the number of cases people try to compare `vector.size()` with `-1`). So your compiler generates a warning to ask you to confirm that's really what you want.